# Facing problems in installing brain.js

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, npm, npm-install, brain.js

I am tying to install brain.js, I first got an error and I installed `python 2.7` but now it's giving another error:

```
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.0 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/node-v16.13.2-headers.tar.gz
...
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.2/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details        
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stocks\prediction\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47) 
...
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\stocks\\prediction\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stocks\prediction\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-14T13_20_57_582Z-debug.log
```

Please help me fix it! Also, I am using `Visual Studio code`. Thank you :)

Comment: Do I need to install Visual Studio to use brain.js

Comment: Take a look at the solutions provided in the _"With NO Visual Studio installed"_ section of the post. (Also see [issue #526](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues/526) in the Github repo)